# how to overload postfix and prefix operator in c#

Tags: c#

How do we implement the overload for postfix and prefix operators in c#

```
void Main()
{
    MyClass myclass=new MyClass();
    myclass.x=5;
    Console.WriteLine((++myclass).x);
          Console.WriteLine((myclass++).x);
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int x;
    public static MyClass operator ++(MyClass m)
    {
        m.x=m.x+1;
        return m;
    }

}
```

this might be an unnecessary operator overload, but its known that ++ operator can be overloaded. How do we achieve the different behaviour here ( i++, ++i)

Comment: public static MyClass operator ++(MyClass m)
     {
      return new MyClass(){x=m.x+1};
     }

works!

Comment: "its known that ++ operator can be overloaded" - I know this is a somewhat dated question but the idea that facts about operators, and overloading rules, are immutable (and findable) rather than being independent concepts in different languages is somewhat odd.